# recorrer formularios hijos mdi segun el orden z actual

Tags: c#

Tengo una apliacion MDI donde tengo un Form padre y varios formularios hijos abiertos como se muestra en la imagen.

la secuencia de apertura de los formularios hijos fue:
form1
form2
form3
form4

Luego cambio el orden de los formularios interponiendolos de distinta manera, pero cuando recorro los formularios hijos mostrando un mensaje por cada iteraccion, no me muestran el orden actual como se encuentran en la imagen, siempre se muestra el siguiente orden como fueron creados incialmente:

form1
form2
form3
form4

en ves de ello, lo que quiero es que se muestre en siguiente orden como la imagen:

form1
form3
form2
form4

alguna idea de como poder conseguirlo

mi codigo esta en el boton del formulario hijo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= MdiParent.MdiChildren.Count() - 1; x++) {
        MessageBox.Show(MdiParent.MdiChildren[x].Text);
    }
}
```

Muchas Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál sería la utilidad de esto?

Comment: necesito identificar que formulario hijo esta adelante de todos top z, luego el que esta detrás de el y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al botton z

Comment: Creo que .net no tiene nada nativo para lo que necesitas, deberás usar funciones del SO. Mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/825595)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!...creo que las funciones API ayudarán

Answer (score 0):

Bueno encontré esta solución, funciona bien a lo expuesto

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

        const uint GW_HWNDFIRST = 0;
        const uint GW_HWNDLAST = 1;
        const uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
        const uint GW_HWNDPREV = 3;



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form fr;
            var hwndTmp = GetWindow(Handle, GW_HWNDFIRST);

            while (hwndTmp != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (Handle == hwndTmp)
                {
                    fr = (Form)Form.FromHandle(hwndTmp);
                    MessageBox.Show(fr.Text);
                }

                hwndTmp = GetWindow(hwndTmp, GW_HWNDNEXT);
                if (hwndTmp != (IntPtr)0)
                {
                    fr = (Form)Form.FromHandle(hwndTmp);
                    MessageBox.Show(fr.Text);
                }

            }

        }
```